# How to set activity to be active all the time?

Tags: java, android

I have activity which needs to be active all the time. I have thread which sleep 10 sec, and monitors values taken from database, compare them and start method. I'm wondering if user go back to other applications and activities, does my activity and thread still work, or they are handled by activity manager and go to pause-stop-destroy?? How to stay them a live??
Thank you.
here is code for that thread:

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while(true){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    myHendler.post(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                            int godina2 = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                            int mesec2 = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                            int dan2 = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                            int sati2 = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                            int minuti2 = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                            trenutniDatum = new StringBuilder().append(dan2).append("-").append(mesec2 +1).append("-").append(godina2);
                            trenutnoVreme = prepraviVreme(sati2) + ":" + prepraviVreme(minuti2);
                            for(int i = 0; i < primljenoIzBazeDatum.length; i++){
                                String bazaBroj = "";
                                String bazaText = "";
                                if(primljenoIzBazeDatum[i].toString().equals(trenutniDatum.toString()) && primljenoIzBazeVreme[i].toString().equals(trenutnoVreme)){

                                        int bazaId = Integer.parseInt(primljenoIzBazeId[i]);
                                        bazaBroj = primljenoIzBazeBroj[i].toString();
                                        bazaText = primljenoIzBazeText[i].toString();
                                        String datumPromena = "*" + primljenoIzBazeDatum[i].toString() + "* SENT *";

                                        datumVreme.open();
                                        datumVreme.updateData(bazaId, datumPromena);
                                        datumVreme.close();

                                        sendPoruka(bazaBroj, bazaText);

                                }

                            } // end for


                        } // end run
                    });
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: Have you considered using a Service ?

Comment: I just reading about it, can you give me some useful advices ?

Comment: I would go with @PeterKnego's answer. Could you clarify if by all the time you mean also while the phone is asleep ??

Comment: Yes even then. Because app needs to check values every 10 s(I change it to 1 minute) and send SMS message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on my understanding of what you want to do, here is what I would do :

First, create a BroadcastReceiver

```
public class Poller extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private final String TAG = "Poller";
    @Override
    public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Poller broadcastintent received");
    Intent myIntent = new Intent( context, PollerService.class );
    context.startService( myIntent );
}
```

then , create the service that is called and then shuts itself down

```
public class PollerService extends Service {
    final String TAG = "PollerService";
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Service onStart()");
    pollingTask.execute();
}

AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> pollingTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... param) {
        // Do what you want in the background
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        stopSelf();
    }
};
}
```

then, set an AlarmManager to wake the service every minute

```
AlarmManager am = ( AlarmManager ) getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE );
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent( "CHECK_DATABASE" );
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0 , alarmIntent, 0 );
int type = AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP;
long interval = POLLING_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS;
long triggerTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + interval;
// For short intervals setInexact repeating is same as exactRepeating, use at least fifteen minutes to make it more efficient
am.setInexactRepeating( type, triggerTime, interval, pi );
Log.i(TAG, "Set inexact alarm through AlarmManager");
}
```

setup the receiver in Android manifest

```
<receiver android:name="Poller">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="CHECK_DATABASE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

finally, unset the AlarmManager to stop polling once your required SMS is received

```
AlarmManager am = ( AlarmManager ) getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE );
Intent intent = new Intent( "CHECK_DATABASE" );
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( context, 0 , intent, 0 );
am.cancel(pi);
```

I do think that Peter is right though and this will kill you battery unless you'll only be checking until you get the required info and then don't poll and that's a short time.

Also, if you can get the exact time when you want to send the SMS with a single call from the database you can just set up the AlarmManger to wake up the service at that time, perform the action and be done with it. That would be the best approach (I can't quite make out if that is the case from you code but it does seems to be from you comments).

Comment: Yes, AlarmManager do work.
Thank you soooo much, I'll organize my code to wake up only in the time when SMS needs to be send.

Comment: Just one more question, in my database I have String in the field of date and time, how can I change that in millisecond, so to now when to set AlarmManager??
Maybe to put one more column in database and when user put date and time to change that in milliseconds and later use it like that?

Comment: Should be simple enough... have a look at SimpleDateFormat. You might concatenate the date and time fields and get a Date using it which can resolved to a long value.

Comment: @Wolf87 you should accept that answer because it's much more informative and helpful (for other users) and it seams like it helped you to fix your problem!

Answer (score 3):

No, no application code on Android is not guaranteed to run all the time. Android OS can kill off aplications and services any time it feels it needs to.

Your best bet to periodically execute code would be to use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), which makes your code execute periodically. Also a proper flag must be set to execute your code when device is asleep.

Note, since your period is very short (10s), it would keep CPU running all the time, draining the batterry very quickly.

Comment: I can change that on 1 min. My app have to send SMS message in user input date and time, so that's why I need to check that every minute.

Answer (score 0):

If it has to be active all the time you have to use a Service: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html

> I'm wondering if user go back to other applications and activities,
>   does my activity and thread still work, or they are handled by
>   activity manager and go to pause-stop-destroy?? How to stay them a
>   live??

They won't be kept "alive". If the system needs the resources your activity is destroyed. If you want to keep things running in the background even after your app is finished you have to use a Service.

Comment: Services can be killed off by the system and are not guaranteed to run all the time. For sure they are not executed when device is in sleep mode.

Comment: You can make sure that they run again as soon as possible with certain return statements in you onStartCommand()-Method.

Answer (score 0):

In Java language you can scheduling your programs by traditional way:

```
java.util.Timer
java.util.TimerTask
```

for more information you can see:

1. http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html
2. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-schedule/index.html

but better practice is using a scheduling framework such as Quartz, you can see http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/.
Spring framework also integration with Quartz framework.