# how to call activity's function from alarm manager

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alarms

I have a `startApplicationService` method in an activity. Therefore I have an alarm manager. `startApplicationService` method is calling background service. I want to use/call that method in `onReceive` method from my alarm manager. How to do it? Please help me. :)

**EDITED: Added alarm manager class:**

```
public class WatcherAlarm  extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    private final static String LOG_TAG = WatcherAlarm.class.getSimpleName();
    private AccessActivity activity = null;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "-------------------------- WATCHER ALARM ------ ON RECEIVE");
        if(activity != null) {
            activity.startApplicationService(intent.getExtras());
        }
    }

    public void startAlarm(AccessActivity activity, Bundle bundle)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(activity, WatcherAlarm.class); // explicit
        i.putExtras(bundle);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity, 0, i, 0);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 20, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
    }

    public void stopAlarm(Context context)
    {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, WatcherAlarm.class); // explicit
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
        alarmManager.cancel(pi);
    }
}
```

And here is the my `startApplicationService` method: It's starting AsyncTask.

```
public void startApplicationService(Bundle bundle)
{
    try {
        task = new ApplicationServiceTask(this);
        requestId = task.execute(bundle).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm tried get activiy from context. But it's not possible. :(. Is there any way to say `call startApplicationService method to activity` from alarm manager?

Thank you for every advice.

Zeck

Comment: Can you declare it to be `static` method.  :P Cos then bob s your uncle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No... because you have no guarantee that the Activity you are trying to call will even exist when your `onReceive()` is called.

What you can do is start that `Activity` using an `Intent` with an Extra indicating that the the caller is you `BroadcastReceiver`. The Activity can then check that Extra and call the method.

However, considering what you appear to want to do. I would recommend going with a `Service`. Since you are doing the work in the background anyways, I don't see a reason for wanting to do it in an Activity (unless, of course, you have a valid reason that does not show here).

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248032/how-to-set-activity-to-be-active-all-the-time/9248321#9248321) for an example of something similar.